# File upload in with Lithium framework

Tags: php, file-upload, lithium

How does Lithium framework file upload work with MySQL? I can find only tutorials and information with MongoDB.  Tried to do that with MySQL but failed, upload doesn't work.

Can someone explain how it works with simple example?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like you would using [plain PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

MongoDB has [GridFS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php) where you can store files, which can be done in MySQL too (using *BLOB*) but is **not** recommended. Use the filesystem instead `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Just want to second greut's comment. Do **not** store files in your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a plugin, much like paperclip for rails. it's called `li3_attachable` and can be found here https://github.com/sandelius/li3_attachable.

It's not ready yet but I hope it should be stable this weekend. I've also added some docs in the wiki.

Comment: li3_attachable is no longer supported or developed - also fails due to changes in lithium core.